# Is there a way to define behavior of struct arithmetic?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct `vec`:

```
struct vec {
    float x, y, z;
}
```

And a method to do arithmetic on two vectors, in this case subtraction:

```
vec* sub(vec* a, vec* b) {
    struct vec* new = (vec*)malloc(sizeof(struct vec));
    new->x = a->x - b->x;
    new->y = a->y - b->y;
    new->z = a->z - b->z;
    return new;
}
```

Behavior of arithmetic with integers, floats, etc is simple:

```
int - int = int
```

But is undefined for `vec`:

```
vec - vec = compiler errors
```

Is there a way to define behavior of operands on structs? Say I just want to type `new = a - b`, is there a way to configure it such that that line does the function `sub`?

Comment: In C, no. C++ adds one.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you could do this in C, you still have to keep track of the dynamically allocated memory that you create, i.e. you have to free the result of each call.  For a case like this, I find it preferable to return the actual structs rather than pointers to them.  That way you don't need to use `malloc` and you can chain the operations together more naturally, albeit using function syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what C++ gives you.  In C, you stick with calling sub.

Another issue is the dynamic allocation, it can get clunky and means you can't work with stack varibles as easily.  Couple of solutions to that, move the allocation out of the subtract

if we typedef the vec :-

```
  typedef struct  { float x, y, z;} vec;
```

then...

```
vec* subtract(vec* l, vec *r, vec *result);
```

you can them build a subtract ontop of this one that also mallocs if you like, but this way the subtract will work with either dynamic or stack based variables.

or by value

```
vec subtract(vec l, vec r);
```

by value is probably best for your small struct,  but, it's up to you.